# How to preview View while Debugging in Android Studio just like in Xcode

Tags: android, xcode, debugging, android-studio

I am trying to debug a weird bug right now. I need to preview how the view has been rendered while debug. We can do this in AS only for bitmaps. Is there anyway for doing this for normal views, like we do in Xcode? Or there is some way for viewing hierarchy of the whole layout at runtime? Thanks.

Comment: I believe the DDMS tools have a Heirachary Viewer.  Been awhile since I've opened it. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html